# how do you flip rows to columns in r?

Tags: r

**I was wondering about how you convert this df**

| Market | Date | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 11/21/21 | 2 |
| Second | 11/21/21 | 3 |
| Third | 11/21/21 | 4 |
| First | 11/22/21 | 9 |
| Second | 11/22/21 | 6 |
| Third | 11/22/21 | 7 |

**to this**

| Date | First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/21/21 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 11/22/21 | 9 | 6 | 7 |

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `pivot_wider` to get the data into the wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Market", values_from = "N")
```

**Output**

```
  Date     First Second Third
  <chr>    <int>  <int> <int>
1 11/21/21     2      3     4
2 11/22/21     9      6     7
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Market = c("First", "Second", "Third", "First", 
"Second", "Third"), Date = c("11/21/21", "11/21/21", "11/21/21", 
"11/22/21", "11/22/21", "11/22/21"), N = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```